# Expand Formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have added new columns to my spreadsheet and have gone from 60 columns (H11:BO11) to 500 (H11:SM11) but my formula has not automatically continued as it involves multiple cells. The only way I can expand it is to type in each new cell to the formula. Does anyone know an easier way?

This is the current formula from H11 to BO11:

```
=IF(D11="",0(IF(H11=$H$10,1,0)+IF(I11=$I$10,1,0)+IF(J11=$J$10,1,0)+IF(K11=$K$10,1,0)+IF(L11=$L$10,1,0)+IF(M11=$M$10,1,0)+IF(N11=$N$10,1,0)+IF(O11=$O$10,1,0)+IF(P11=$P$10,1,0)+IF(Q11=$Q$10,1,0)+IF(R11=$R$10,1,0)+IF(S11=$S$10,1,0)+IF(T11=$T$10,1,0)+IF(U11=$U$10,1,0)+IF(V11=$V$10,1,0)+IF(W11=$W$10,1,0)+IF(X11=$X$10,1,0)+IF(Y11=$Y$10,1,0)+IF(Z11=$Z$10,1,0)+IF(AA11=$AA$10,1,0)+IF(AB11=$AB$10,1,0)+IF(AC11=$AC$10,1,0)+IF(AD11=$AD$10,1,0)+IF(AE11=$AE$10,1,0)+IF(AF11=$AF$10,1,0)+IF(AG11=$AG$10,1,0)+IF(AH11=$AH$10,1,0)+IF(AI11=$AI$10,1,0)+IF(AJ11=$AJ$10,1,0)+IF(AK11=$AK$10,1,0)+IF(AL11=$AL$10,1,0)+IF(AM11=$AM$10,1,0)+IF(AN11=$AN$10,1,0)+IF(AO11=$AO$10,1,0)+IF(AP11=$AP$10,1,0)+IF(AQ11=$AQ$10,1,0)+IF(AR11=$AR$10,1,0)+IF(AS11=$AS$10,1,0)+IF(AT11=$AT$10,1,0)+IF(AU11=$AU$10,1,0)+IF(AV11=$AV$10,1,0)+IF(AW11=$AW$10,1,0)+IF(AX11=$AX$10,1,0)+IF(AY11=$AY$10,1,0)+IF(AZ11=$AZ$10,1,0)+IF(BA11=$BA$10,1,0)+IF(BB11=$BB$10,1,0)+IF(BC11=$BC$10,1,0)+IF(BD11=$BD$10,1,0)+IF(BE11=$BE$10,1,0)+IF(BF11=$BF$10,1,0)+IF(BG11=$BG$10,1,0)+IF(BH11=$BH$10,1,0)+IF(BI11=$BI$10,1,0)+IF(BJ11=$BJ$10,1,0)+IF(BK11=$BK$10,1,0)+IF(BL11=$BL$10,1,0)+IF(BM11=$BM$10,1,0)+IF(BN11=$BN$10,1,0)+IF(BO11=$BO$10,1,0)))
```

Comment: Did you create a table or just range?

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to count how many columns has changed compared to the previous row.

```
=SUM(--(H11:SM11=H10:SM10))
```

Commit this array formula using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and not just ENTER. This tells excel to work with array vectors and not just scalar single cells.